# How to recover my funds from electrum wallet with privatekey and redeem script?

Tags: wallet, electrum, private-key-import

Hey I think I know the answer already and I kinda screwed up I think I just want to verify. so I send BTC to my electrum wallet and I forgot the seed. I could not find it. but I have the private key and redeem script. is there any chance to restore or gain access to the funds or do I have to say goodbye for ever? thanks in advance if anyone has an idea otherwise I will have to accept my faith and add a learning experience to my repertoire. thanks in advance.

Comment: what type of wallet was it? electrum doesn't let you input the redeem script when importing or sweeping private keys. however it may be able to generate the redeem script itself depending on the wallet type.

Comment: well thats the thing its a two factor auth. but i never remebered to actually set two fact. up so it confused my right away and now i cant acces my funds because it needs the 2fa when sending which i dont have so thats it right? its just a watch adress now for me and i cant do anything if im correct. if there is another possibility please let me know :)

Comment: 2fa means it's a multisig 2 of 3 wallet with 3 private keys behind each address and you need any 2 of those to spend. one private key will not be enough. if you have the wallet installed on your device you can try number 3 [here](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/how-to-recover-access-to-the-bitcoins-in-your-2fa-wallet/).